# If $X_1, X_2,Y$ are three random variables, and $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$, is it possible to reduce $E[Y\mid X_1, X_2]$?

Tags: probability

If $X_1, X_2,Y$ are three random variables, and $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$, is it possible to reduce $E[Y\mid X_1, X_2]$ to something like $E[Y\mid X_1]E[Y\mid X_2]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not even close. For example, suppose $Y$ is always between $2$ and $3.$ Then $\operatorname{E}(Y)$ is between $2$ and $3$ and $\operatorname{E}(Y\mid \cdots\cdots)$ is between $2$ and $3$ regardless of what the condition is.

Since $\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X_1)$ is always between $2$ and $3$, and so is $\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X_2)$, we have
$\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X_1) \cdot\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X_2)$ between $4$ and $9,$ although $\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X_1,X_1)$ must be between $2$ and $3.$

Comment: So in general there is no way to decompose it as a general case?

Comment: Yes, there is no way to further reduce it as a general case.